# Tensorflow custom op, gpu kernel returns a tensor of zeros

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, cuda

I am trying to implement a custom op and I am using the example in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op) as a benchmark to test the correct compilation of the op, I've just modified the gpu kernel in order to see if it was actually executed but when I test the op it returns all zeros.

kernel_example.h

```py
// kernel_example.h
#ifndef KERNEL_EXAMPLE_H_
#define KERNEL_EXAMPLE_H_

#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

template <typename Device, typename T>
struct ExampleFunctor {
  void operator()(const Device& d, int size, const T* in, T* out);
};

#if GOOGLE_CUDA
// Partially specialize functor for GpuDevice.
template <typename T>
struct ExampleFunctor<Eigen::GpuDevice, T> {
  void operator()(const Eigen::GpuDevice& d, int size, const T* in, T* out);
};
#endif

#endif
```

kernel_example.cc

```py
// kernel_example.cc
#include "kernel_example.h"

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

using CPUDevice = Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice;
using GPUDevice = Eigen::GpuDevice;

REGISTER_OP("Example")
    .Attr("T: numbertype")
    .Input("input: T")
    .Output("input_times_two: T")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      return Status::OK();
    });

// CPU specialization of actual computation.
template <typename T>
struct ExampleFunctor<CPUDevice, T> {
  void operator()(const CPUDevice& d, int size, const T* in, T* out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      out[i] = 2 * in[i];
    }
  }
};

// OpKernel definition.
// template parameter <T> is the datatype of the tensors.
template <typename Device, typename T>
class ExampleOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ExampleOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);

    // Create an output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                     &output_tensor));

    // Do the computation.
    OP_REQUIRES(context, input_tensor.NumElements() <= tensorflow::kint32max,
                errors::InvalidArgument("Too many elements in tensor"));
    ExampleFunctor<Device, T>()(
        context->eigen_device<Device>(),
        static_cast<int>(input_tensor.NumElements()),
        input_tensor.flat<T>().data(),
        output_tensor->flat<T>().data());
  }
};

// Register the CPU kernels.
#define REGISTER_CPU(T)                                          \
  REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(                                       \
      Name("Example").Device(DEVICE_CPU).TypeConstraint<T>("T"), \
      ExampleOp<CPUDevice, T>);
REGISTER_CPU(float);
REGISTER_CPU(int32);

// Register the GPU kernels.
#ifdef GOOGLE_CUDA
#define REGISTER_GPU(T)                                          \
  /* Declare explicit instantiations in kernel_example.cu.cc. */ \
  extern template class ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, T>;            \
  REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(                                       \
      Name("Example").Device(DEVICE_GPU).TypeConstraint<T>("T"), \
      ExampleOp<GPUDevice, T>);
REGISTER_GPU(float);
REGISTER_GPU(int32);
#endif  // GOOGLE_CUDA
```

kernel_example.cu.cc

```py
// kernel_example.cu.cc
#ifdef GOOGLE_CUDA
#define EIGEN_USE_GPU
#include "kernel_example.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/gpu_kernel_helper.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

using GPUDevice = Eigen::GpuDevice;

// Define the CUDA kernel.
template <typename T>
__global__ void ExampleCudaKernel(const int size, const T* in, T* out) {
  for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < size;
       i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
    out[i] = 3 * __ldg(in + i); # modified to check if it is executed
  }
}

// Define the GPU implementation that launches the CUDA kernel.
template <typename T>
void ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, T>::operator()(
    const GPUDevice& d, int size, const T* in, T* out) {
  // Launch the cuda kernel.
  //
  // See core/util/gpu_kernel_helper.h for example of computing
  // block count and thread_per_block count.
  int block_count = 1024;
  int thread_per_block = 20;
  ExampleCudaKernel<T>
      <<<block_count, thread_per_block, 0, d.stream()>>>(size, in, out);
}

// Explicitly instantiate functors for the types of OpKernels registered.
template struct ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, float>;
template struct ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, int32>;

#endif  // GOOGLE_CUDA
```

To compile the op I use the following Makefile

```
# Makefile
TF_COM = `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(' '.join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))"`
TF_INC = `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())"`
TF_LIN = `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(' '.join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))"`

CC        = gcc -O2 -pthread
GPUDEF    = -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1

# nvcc: cuda kernel compilation to obtain .o file
GPUCC     = nvcc
GPUCFLAGS = -std=c++14 -I$(TF_INC) --expt-relaxed-constexpr -c
GPULFLAGS = -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC

GPUSRC    = kernel_example.cu.cc
GPUPROD   = kernel_example.cu.o


# g++: combines the source .cc and the gpu prod .o to create a .so
CXX       = g++ -O2
CFLAGS    = -std=c++14 $(TF_COM)
LFLAGS    = -shared -fPIC $(TF_LIN) 
LCUDA     = -lcuda -L /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64/

SRC       = kernel_example.cc
PROD      = kernel_example.so


default: gpu

cpu:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC) $(LFLAGS) -o $(PROD)

gpu:
    $(GPUCC) $(GPUCFLAGS) $(GPUSRC) $(GPULFLAGS) $(GPUDEF) -o $(GPUPROD)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC) $(GPUPROD) $(LFLAGS) $(LCUDA) $(GPUDEF) -o $(PROD)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROD) $(GPUPROD)
```

I'm currently working directly on google Colab, loading the previous files in `/content` and running the compilation with the following lines

```
!mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/third_party/gpus/cuda/
!ln -s /usr/local/cuda/include /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/third_party/gpus/cuda/
!make gpu
```

The cpu op compilation works fine. The gpu op compilation does not give any error but when I test the op it does not work properly.

With an input of `input = tf.ones((4,))`, considered the update I made in the gpu kernel, I expect to get `[3., 3., 3., 3.]` but I actually get `[0., 0., 0., 0.]`, when eager execution is active.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

kernel_example_module = tf.load_op_library('/content/kernel_example.so')
example = kernel_example_module.example

input = tf.ones((4,))
output = .example(input)
print(output.numpy())
```

Whereas when I run the same in graph mode I get `[2., 2., 2., 2.]`, which is the result I obtain from the cpu implementation, this makes me think the gpu kernel is kind not executed.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

kernel_example_module = tf.load_op_library('/content/kernel_example.so')
example = kernel_example_module.example

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    input = tf.ones((4,))
    output = example(input)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
```

I've tried to link the cuda path in the Makefile (LCUDA), as suggested in another similar question, but this did not solve my problem. I feel something is wrong with compiling options but I really cannot find what the problem could be.

Any idea how to make the gpu kernel work correctly ?

Comment: If I follow the instructions given in your question, I get a "No rule to make target 'gpu'" error. Is this the right format for makefile?

Comment: Did you check for the right `tab` indentation in the Makefile? If you have 4 white spaces it does not work, you should insert tab symbols that in Visual Studio are represented by right arrows when highlighted

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem. After several trials I saw that sometimes it worked and sometimes not, I finally ended up in understanding that the reason was due to the specific GPU I was connected with and that adding the flag -arch to the nvcc compilation was the solution. In Colab you can see the Gpu model through `!nvidia-smi`.

- Tesla K80: `-arch=sm_37`, it's deprecated but it currently works.
- Tesla T4: you don't need to specify anything.

Check this [link](https://arnon.dk/tag/nvcc-flags/#:%7E:text=When%20compiling%20with%20NVCC%2C%20the,many%20times%20for%20different%20architectures.) to find what -arch you need to specify. For completeness I report the Makefile you need to use when you are connected to a Tesla K80:

```
TF_CFLAGS = `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(' '.join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))"`
TF_LFLAGS = `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(' '.join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))"`

default: gpu
gpu:
    nvcc -std=c++14 -c -o kernel_example.cu.o kernel_example.cu.cc $(TF_CFLAGS) -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC --expt-relaxed-constexpr -arch=sm_37
    g++ -std=c++14 -shared -o kernel_example.so kernel_example.cc kernel_example.cu.o $(TF_CFLAGS) -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -fPIC -L/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64/ -lcudart -lcuda $(TF_LFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. I do not remember if this was the trick that solved my problem, but try launching your CUDA kernel like this:

```py
// Get the optimal number of blocks and threads
GpuLaunchConfig config = GetGpuLaunchConfig(size, d);
// Launch the kernel
TF_CHECK_OK(::tensorflow::GpuLaunchKernel(ExampleCudaKernel <T>,
    config.block_count, config.thread_per_block, 0, d.stream(),
    size, in, out
));
```